# Python - from Script to Web App?

Tags: python, web-services, web-applications

I have a Python script that can run in command line/console which works with the Google Calendar Data API to do some tasks like retrieve calendars and modify or update events. I want to turn it into a web application/interface, but was not sure what would be the optimal or simplest way going about it.

Some precursor information: I tried rewriting the application as .html files that used Javascript and its respective Google Calendar Data API. I ran into a few problems with that and found that it wasn't working as well as my Python script. It could possibly be because I am using a business gmail domain but I'm not entirely sure. It does however work fine with Python, so I've decided to stick with that.

I've only worked with Python scripts (and I'd only call myself a beginner), so I'm not sure what would be an ideal or optimal solution. I'd preferably (re: if even possible) like to have the Python script act as a backend/web-service and interface with a website through JSON, or use a Python webframework to develop it. I hope I got the bulk of my terminology right, my apologies if anything is unclear.

Any advice is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Some frameworks to check out: Django, Flask, web.py, Pyramid

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rafe. I've checked out some of the frameworks, I also heard of a few others such as Twisted and Tornado. I just wasn't sure if going down that route would be the best option for me and figured it couldn't hurt to ask first before going and trying something out.

Comment: Twisted isn't really a web application frame, it's more of a networking framework. Tornado is good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go check out Google App Engine. There's a Python API. It works well with other Google services, like Calendar. Probably the fastest way to get where you want to go.

Comment: I should also note I've done exactly what you've described. Started with a python script which manipulated calendar data and moved it to a GAE app with an html interface.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, would you happen to have some numbers on how much monthly bandwidth is consumed? I don't know how much data is transferred and am wondering if the 500MB bandwidth is sufficient.

Comment: From Google's App Engine Billing FAQ: An application without billing enabled is allocated 1 GB of persistent storage and enough CPU and bandwidth for about 5 million page views a month. The Admin Console's Quotas page lists every quota and provides a breakdown of how much your application is consuming per resource.

Comment: I've never even come close to this limit with my piddly little app:)

Answer (score 0):

Google Appengine would be much easier for you in terms of getting a web application available and up on the web. You might want to look at the way it stores data (Appengine's datastore) as it maybe different than how you would store things in a RDBMS.

You could use the gdata-python-client with Appengine. Please refer to "Using the gdata-python-client" library [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/python/retrieving_gdata_feeds.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to set up a web service that returns JSON, the [web2py](http://www.web2py.com) framework makes that very easy (see [here](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/09)). It also runs out-of-the-box on Google App Engine -- you can even deploy to GAE directly from web2py's web-based IDE ([demo](http://www.web2py.com/demo_admin/gae/deploy)). If you have any questions, you'll get lots of help from the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/web2py).